# Getting the positions of a object when you click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/85/

It displays the position of bean 1 (box 1) when you move it around the page, but how I display the position of the second box? I want it to be able to display the position of whatever I click on.

So if I clicked on box 1 and moved it, it will display X and Y of the first box

If I licked on box 2 and moved it, it should display the X,Y of second box.

This is the part of the code where it shows the X and Y positions:

```
   $( "*", document ).on('click',function( event ) {
            var offset = $( "strong" ).offset();
            topp = offset.top;
            left = offset.left;
            event.stopPropagation();
            $( "#result" ).text( this.tagName +
            "  ( " + left + ", " + topp + " )" + offset.id );


}
```

Also, why is the id undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**draggable has a built in stop event**

So it may make sense to use that.

**something like this:**

```
$('.normal, .failure').draggable({//drag
    stop: function() {//on stop
        var t = parseInt($(this).position().top),//get top
            l = parseInt($(this).position().left);//get left
        $( "#result" ).text( this.tagName+' ('+l+', '+t+') '+this.id);//print
    }
});
```

**made a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/8MVT9/

And the `ID` is undefined, because `$( "strong" ).offset().id` isn't correct, it would need to be `$( "strong" ).prop('id')` or something equivalent. Though `strong` doesn't have an `ID`, so it still wouldn't work... you need the `ID` of `.normal` & `.failure` for it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is undefined because there is no id in the `.offset()` method. You are doing

```
$( "strong" ).offset().id
```

and offset only returns top and left, there is no id. That is why it is undefined.

Now to handle the issue with it returning the first item. The code

```
var offset = $( "strong" ).offset();
```

is also only looking at one element, if you want what was clicked you would use this

```
var elem = $(this);
var offset = elem.offset();
```

and to get the id

```
elem.attr("id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you whant is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/86/

instead of this:

```
var offset = $( "strong" ).offset();
```

I've done this:

```
var offset = $( this ).offset();
```

check the fiddle to see if that works

for the id, you should also change it to $(this).id

http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/88/

but you have to add the ID to the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$( "*", document ).on('click',function( event ) {
            var offset = $( this ).offset();
            topp = offset.top;
            left = offset.left;
            event.stopPropagation();
            $( "#result" ).text( this.tagName +
            "  ( " + left + ", " + topp + " )" + offset.id );


}
```

EDIT:

As id is undefined, it is part of a parent node, you have to notice that the node you select in each bean can be different and the access to the property can be variable (this, this.parentNode, etc), so you need to place it in a right place or set the event handler to specific elements.

Comment: id will still be undefined

Comment: I think id was just an example to show which element was dragged and is not that important, by the way, I don't know if it's enough for him/her.

Comment: Well they asked "Also, why is the id undefined?"

Comment: @EdgarAlexander What if he needs the id to run some other calculations?  People normally don't include excessive code.

Comment: @epascerello Ops, by bad

Answer (score 1):

**This:**

```
var offset = $( "strong" ).offset();
```

**Should be this:**

```
var offset = $( this ).offset();
```

**Undefined ID:**

For the undefined id, first there is no .id for the offest() method.  Second, the only elements that have id's are the containers in the back.  When you click on the boxes, you're actually clicking on the divs or p's in front, not the ones with the id's in the back.  So if you want an id, you will need to add it to the p or div out front.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsaat14/j988J/6/)**.